# Как пользоваться областью видимости private в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть `public`: то, что по умолчанию.
Также есть `protected` (защищенный) и `private` — вообще не используется за пределами зоны видимости (это если я верно понял)!

Каким образом он вообще используется, если даже экземпляр класса не имеет доступа (это надо уточнить)?

Непонятно, что значит всё это и как верно применять?

Comment: Это, так сказать, личное свойство экземпляра. Вы же будете против, если к вам залезет кто-то в карман, даже если он также, как и вы, изучает php.

Comment: *"экземпляр класса не имеет доступа"* -- вот как раз экземпляр класса и имеет. Но не его потомки.

Comment: как бы , оформите ответом плиз .. я понимаю как выглядит но не понимаю как применять

Comment: @Geyan, а самому почитать учебник по основам - не?

Comment: @PinkTux т.е получается если объест private то экземпляр его унаследует свойства ? можно так ? я прочитал их уже 2 , там ни чего ни ясно

Comment: @Geyan, что там может быть неясного? Наследуются все поля в любом случае, а спецификаторы доступа задают режим доступа к ним. `public` - доступ для всех. `protected` - только для экземпляра класса и его наследников. `private` - только для экземпляра класса, в котором они объявлены. Всё. Если в ваших учебниках этого нет - ищите другие.

Comment: @PinkTux в смысле экземпляр класса имеет доступ? может быть вы ошиблись? Сам класс имеет доступ к своим приватным полям и методам, а экземпляр класса — нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, *"экземпляр класса — нет"* - как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: @PinkTux нет... как раз-таки как **вы** себе представляете доступ экземпляра к приватным полям и методам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, пожалуйста, вот экземпляр класса `aaa` обращается к своему приватному полю во время вызова метода: http://ideone.com/siYuiN Объясните почему он не сможет этого сделать?

Comment: @PinkTux нет. вы обращаетесь к публичному методу, который уже внутри класса обращается к своему приватному полю....а вот обращение экземпляра к приватному полю `$A->a` невозможно и вызовет ошибку `Cannot access private property`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а в данном случае происходит обращение к приватному полю какой-то сущностью, которая не является экземпляром данного класса, потому и ошибка. В любом случае я не вижу никакого запрета на доступ к полям для экземпляра класса.

Comment: @PinkTux `сущностью, которая не является экземпляром данного класса,` - эм... Объект — экземпляр класса. Который создается через директиву `new` по схеме, описанной этим классом......или у вас экземпляр класса — это какое-то своё понятие?